# Strip at center in tabhost

Tags: android

I am using the tabhost in the application. But I am facing the problem that There is strip at center in the tab. Is there any way to remove that.

I added the below code which i am using for the tabhost.

[image]

```
int tabCount = tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount();
for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
    final View view = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);
    if ( view != null ) {
        // reduce height of the tab
        view.getLayoutParams().height *= 0.80;

        //  get title text view
        final View textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        if ( textView instanceof TextView ) {
            // just in case check the type

            // center text
            ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            // wrap text
            ((TextView) textView).setSingleLine(false);

            // explicitly set layout parameters
            textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
            textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }
    }
}
```

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the divider?

Comment: Middle line above the Zoznam. I am not aware about the exactly word for this.

Comment: Off the cuff, that looks like a problem with the custom drawable you are using for your tab background.

Comment: Delete `view.getLayoutParams().height *= 0.80;` and see if your line goes away.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok I am trying..

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks you very much..I know about you...proud of you..great..!!!